# why $||T_n||=1 ?$ Kreyszig Book Example $4.9-2$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some confusion in  Functional analysis- Kreyszig book

In the book it is written that

> In the   space $l^2 $  we consider a  sequenec$(T_n)$ , where  $T_n: l^2 \to l^2$ is defined by
> $T_nx=(0,0,0,....0, e_{n+1},e_{n+2},.....) $
> Here  , $x=(e_1,e_2,....) \in l^2$.

> This operator  $T_n$ is linear and bounded ,
> clearly $(T_n)$  is not uniformly  operator  convergent   since we have $||T_n-0||=||T_n||=1$

Im not getting why $||T_n||=1 ?$

**My thinking** :Here $$||T_n||=\sup\{||T_nx|| | x \in l^2 , ||x||_{l^2}=0\}$$

$||x||_{l^2}=0$ because $\sum x_n^2 <\infty$ in $l^2$ space

So i think $$||T_n||=0 \neq 1$$ .

Comment: Consider $x = e_{n+1}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams $\sum e_{n+1}^2=0 \implies ||T_n||=0$

Comment: Based on your post and that comment, I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding some basic details about operator norms. Think about $T_1$. $T_1(x_1, x_2,x_3\ldots) = (0,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$. If you consider a specific sequence, say.. $(1,1,1,0,0,\ldots)$, what do you get?

Comment: Actually  , im new to the functional analysis  @CameronWilliams $T_1(1,1,1,0,0,...,)=(0,1,1,0,...,)$

Comment: that $||x||_{\ell_2}=0$ in your definition of $||T_n||$ is simply wrong. You should start by looking up the correct definition of $||T||$.

Comment: I think David has it right. $$\|T\| \equiv \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Tx\|. $$ There are a handful of other equivalences. For any linear operator, $\sup_{\|x\| = 0} \|Tx\|$ will be $0$ since the only vector with norm $0$ is the zero vector and any linear operator takes the zero vector to the zero vector.

Comment: It is quite clear that $\|T_n\| \leq 1.$ For the reverse inequality what about taking $T_n e_k$ where $k \geq n+1,$ where $e_k$ is the $k$-th coordinate vector?

Answer (score 1):

From  cameron williams comment

$\|T_n\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \|T_n(x)\|=||x||=1$

Take $x=e_{n+1}$ , $||e_{n+1}||=1$